# How do I make a generic type function to map the return types of each key?

Tags: typescript

If I have

```
type T1 = {
  a: () => string,
  b: () => number
}

type T2 = {
  [P in keyof T1]: ReturnType<T1[P]>
}
```

Then T2 is

```
{
  a: string,
  b: number
}
```

How do I make a generic type function to map the return types, assuming each key of the generic type is a function?

```
type MapReturnType<T extends Record<string, ???>> = {
  [P in keyof T]: ReturnType<T[P]>
}
```

Comment: I believe you can use `() => any` in place of `???`

Comment: @Spikatrix that works, thanks! to make it more generic, (...args: any) => any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `() => any` as the value you have is a function

```
type MapReturnType<T extends Record<string, () => any>> = {
  [P in keyof T]: ReturnType<T[P]>
}
```